# Brunch plugin pipline issues

Tags: brunch

I'm writing a plugin for Brunch to 'filter' files from code library. Basic idea is to:

1. check my source files (in `src\` folder, or any watched folders that don't match library pattern),
2. build a list of imported/required modules from code library (in `lib\` folder, outside `src\`, somewhere on disk)
3. check files against this list and 'approve' or 'reject' them
4. compile only what's 'approved', so I don't end up with huge files that have all modules/components from my library, but only what I use in particular project

When I work only with JavaScript files `this.pattern = /.*(js|jsx)$/;` everything  works fine. Next step is to include more files, since many modules/components in library have some sort of template or stylesheets, for example this is one AngularJS module:

```
lib\
  modules\
    pager\
      controller.jsx
      directive.jsx
      template.html
      pager.styl
      README.md
```

But when I expand the pattern to include other files `this.pattern = /.*/;`, I run into all sorts of issues (; Most have to do with pipline - those are the kinds of errors I'm getting. For example:

- jshint-brunch doesn't like README.md
- html-brunch won't wrap template.html
- stylus-brunch and sass-brunch are also unhappy

I've tried solving these problems individually, for example if I disable html-brunch `config.plugins.off: ['html-brunch']`, and add this code inside the compiler function, it kinda works:

```
  if( params.path.match(/.html$/) ) {
    params.data = "module.exports = function() { return " + JSON.stringify(params.data) + ";};";
    return callback(null, this.config.modules.wrapper(params.path, params.data));
  }
```

..but I couldn't resolve all the issues. Pretty much all problems have to do with  this line in the compiler function: `return callback(null, null);`. When I 'reject' a file next plugin gets something undefined and breaks...

#### Any ideas how to solve this?

I'd like to eventually expand plugin's functionality to handle static assets too, for example copy `lib\images\placeholder-1.jpg` (but not `placeholder-2.jpg`) from library if it's used in html files, but I'm stuck at this point...

Here's the code of the plugin:

```
var CodeLibrary;

module.exports = CodeLibrary = (function() {
  var required = [];
  CodeLibrary.prototype.brunchPlugin = true;

  function CodeLibrary(config) {
    this.config  = config;
    this.pattern = /.*/;
    this.watched = this.config.paths.watched.filter(function(path) {
      return !path.match( config.plugins.library.pattern );
    });
  }

  function is_required(path) {
    var name = this.config.modules.nameCleaner(path);
    return required.some(function(e, i, a) { return name.match(e); });
  }
  function in_library(path) {
    return Boolean(path.match( this.config.plugins.library.pattern ));
  }
  function is_watched(path) {
    return this.watched.some(function(e, i, a) { return path.match( e ); });
  }

  CodeLibrary.prototype.lint = function(data, path, callback) {
    if( !is_watched.apply(this, [path]) && 
        !is_required.apply(this, [path]) ) 
      return callback();

    var es6_pattern = /import .*'(.*)'/gm;
    var commonjs_pattern = /require\('(.*)'\)/gm;   

    var match = es6_pattern.exec(data) || commonjs_pattern.exec(data);

    while( match != null ) {
      if( required.indexOf(match[1]) === -1 ) 
        required.push( match[1] );
      match = es6_pattern.exec(data) || commonjs_pattern.exec(data);
    }
    callback();
  }
  CodeLibrary.prototype.compile = function(params, callback) {
    if( is_required.apply(this, [params.path]) || 
       !in_library.apply(this, [params.path]) )
      return callback(null, params);

    return callback(null, null);
  };

  return CodeLibrary;

})();
```

Comment: Do you load your plugin before `html-brunch` for example etc.? The order in `package.json` matters.

Comment: I don't believe I do, at least I didn't pay attention to this (: I did notice it executes early (with build --debug). I will try to change order and report back the results... Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: I've tried loading my plugin before all others, but that didn't work - even babel-brunch that worked before broke with same error. Then I tried loading my plugin last, and it works. There's an issue with stylus-brunch compiling same files more then once, but I can live with that for now (: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction Paul!